# Python compare objects in C API

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

Given two `PyObject*`s, how can I compare them in C API?

I thought of `a == b` at first, but it's clearly incorrect since it would compare the pointer and not the object. I'm looking for `a == b` (not `a is b`) Python equivalent in Python C API.

Answer (score 13):

You are looking for the `PyObject_RichCompare` function:

```
PyObject *result = PyObject_RichCompare(a, b, Py_EQ);
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare):

> `PyObject* PyObject_RichCompare(PyObject *o1, PyObject *o2, int opid)`
>
> *Return value: New reference.*
>
> Compare the values of `o1` and `o2` using the operation specified by `opid`, which must be one of `Py_LT`, `Py_LE`, `Py_EQ`, `Py_NE`, `Py_GT`, or
>   `Py_GE`, corresponding to `<`, `<=`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, or `>=` respectively. This is
>   the equivalent of the Python expression `o1 op o2`, where `op` is the
>   operator corresponding to `opid`. Returns the value of the comparison on
>   success, or `NULL` on failure.

You might also be interested in the [`PyObject_RichCompareBool` function](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompareBool), which does the same as `PyObject_RichCompare` but returns an integer rather than a `PyObject *`.  Specifically, `1` is returned for true, `0` for false, and `-1` for an error.

Comment: What about comparing is or is not.

Comment: Very belatedly: `is` and `is not` are just whether the pointers are equal.