# How to access Python dunder methods in C using CFFI?

Tags: c, python-3.x, python-cffi

I was trying to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890418/simplest-possible-python-cffi-example) to attempt to create a simple hash table in C that I could use in Python (using CFFI). Following are the corresponding files and relevant code.

`hash_table.h`:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    ...
    int cmp_function(const PyObject*, const PyObject*);
} hash_table_t;
```

`build_hash_table.py`:

```
from cffi import cffi

HEADER_FILE_NAME = "hash_table.h"
SOURCE_FILE_NAME = "hash_table.c"

ffi = FFI()

header = open(HEADER_FILE_NAME, "rt").read()
source = open(SOURCE_FILE_NAME, "rt").read()

ffi.set_source("hashtable.hash_table", header + source)
ffi.cdef(header)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    ffi.compile()
```

Now, everything so far works. However, I am going to want to insert whatever data types in the hash table. How do I get access to whatever object I am receiving within the C code? For example, say I had this class in Python:

```
class Person():

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

When I am searching for `Person` objects in the hash table, how do I access the `__eq__` method? As you can see above, I have a generic compare function declared as `int cmp_function(const void*, const void*);` in the hash table. The goal would be that every time I search for an object, I can know the `__eq__` method definition of that object - in the C side.

Hope I made my question clear, thank you in advance!

Comment: Your objects should not be `void *` but `PyObject *` then...

Comment: they should not be const. Anyway, the access requires CPython, doesn't work in PyPy etc...

Comment: If I'm only using them for comparison, for what reason would I not want them to be const? Either way, I'm fine with the code only being compatible with CPython - of course, a more portable option would be good to know too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#extern-python-and-void-arguments.  Avoid using `PyObject *` with CFFI.  The correct answer is to keep `int cmp_function(const void*, const void*);`.  I will assume that you already use `ffi.new_handle()` to convert the objects to the `void *` equivalent that you can send to C (in the `add_to_hash_table()` method, etc.) and `ffi.from_handle()` to read them back (in the `get_from_hash_table()` method, etc.).

To implement the comparison function, you declare a function in Python with `extern "Python"`, as in the above document.  Then you use that function for the `cmp_function` pointer in your struct.  Inside that Python function, you receive the two arguments as two `void *`.  You first convert them back to the original Python objects with `ffi.from_handle()`, and then just use regular Python---in your case, probably just `if x == y: return 1; else: return 0` or similar.

Be careful about keeping the Python objects alive after calling `ffi.new_handle()`.  They are not kept alive just by the fact that their `void *` representation happens to be stored inside some C structures.

Note that CFFI is not quite well suited to implement pure data structures, because all these conversions and multiple storages that increase the overhead when compared with the direct CPython-C-API approach.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had not yet seen the `new_handle` and `from_handle` functions. By "declare a function in Python with `extern "Python"` you mean in the C header file? As to the comparison function, I need to know how to compare objects in the C side of things - if I'm inserting a new element in the hash table, I need to know if that element is already there. So I would need to "retrieve" the comparison function from Python.

Comment: Also regarding CFFI not being appropriate for the job, I followed [these docs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#:~:text=the%20Python%20Interpreter%20%C2%BB-,1.,library%20functions%20and%20system%20calls.), which said CFFI would increase portability. Thank you for the heads-up though :)

Comment: Quoting: "For example, if your use case is calling C library functions or system calls, you should consider using the ctypes module or the cffi library rather than writing custom C code."  Note how it mentions invoking library or system calls, but not implementing a pure data structure.

Comment: About "declare a function in Python with `extern "Python"`: I mean as documented in detail at the URL https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#extern-python-and-void-arguments .

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be looking for another to compare Python objects in C, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175295/python-compare-objects-in-c-api) which explains exactly how to do that.